# Powershell command to run for everyone

Tags: powershell

I am running into a problem with a PowerShell script. I want to add a Microsoft store app with a PowerShell command:

```
Add-Appxpackage -path C:\Temp\whiteboard.appx
```

The command is working fine, but only for 1 user not for everyone. It must be installed for everyone. How can that be done?

Answer (score 0):

As @WafflesAndCustard already mentioned, the issue for executing the script is the ExecutionPolicy.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7

The PowerShell-Script Execution takes another road as you probably might think of ... PS-User-Policy takes precedence over PS-Computer-Policy, but Local- (gpedit) and Domain-Policies (gpmc) overrides anything and takes the final precedence (Domain policies have highest priority)

By default -> no PowerShell Script execution is allowed.

When you want to use your script for all users, without predefining the PS-executionpolicy, you should use the native command like

```bsh
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -Script ....
```

### BUT, and that's really **IMPORTANT** when it comes to security:

Please don't use the temp folder as this is usual something everybody can write to!

E.g. a user/program can place a malicious executable file into that folder with same name and your task (or whatever) will execute it with high privileges.